# Difference PCA by sklearn (SVD) and scratch PCA (Eigenvector Decomposition)

Tags: scikit-learn, data-analysis, pca, svd, eigenvector

While implementing PCA from scratch, I discovered that PCA by sklearn uses **Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)** while all tutorials implement PCA using **Eigenvalue Decomposition**. They lead to different eigenvectors.

In PCA by sklearn:

```
self.mean_ = np.mean(X, axis=0)
X -= self.mean_

U, S, Vt = scipy.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
# flip eigenvectors' sign to enforce deterministic output
U, Vt = svd_flip(U, Vt)

eig_vec = Vt
```

Scratch PCA:

```
self.mean_ = np.mean(X, axis=0)
X -= self.mean_
covX = np.cov(X)
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(X)
```

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpD9XlTu3ys) for intuition of what SVD is, and this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320220/intuitively-what-is-the-difference-between-eigendecomposition-and-singular-valu) that states the intuitive difference:

*Eigendecomposition represents A in terms of how it scales vectors it doesn't rotate, while singular value decomposition represents A in terms of corresponding vectors that are scaled the same, whether moving from the left to the right space or vice-versa. When the left and right space are the same (i.e. when A is square), singular value decomposition represents A in terms of how it rotates and reflects vectors that A and AT scale by the same amount.*

But I'm wondering why it is done differently ? And especially **what is the difference in the resulting principal components ?**